# tarruda datetimepicker link does not working on https

Tags: datetimepicker, mixed-content

I am using tarruda datetimepicker for my project, it works all good until I move to `https`. Tarruda datetimepicker link is `http`. I get warning 
`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsite.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host the file locally or change the link to use https -- https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css. I'd prefer hosting the file locally over the link as it is not a CDN and the owner can choose to discontinue the Github page, essentially killing your link.